# Retrieving float values from the list in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, floating-point

I am trying to fetch the values from an list containing float values which throws the following error,

```
list = [0.98,0.97,0.95,0.96,0.99,0.99]


for a in list:
    if list[a] >=0.98:
        print("some output")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a` is already the value, so you can do:

```
for a in list:
    if a >=0.98:
        print("some output")
```

If it was the index, your code will work, but since it isn't, you have to do mine.

Comment: how to append values in single dictionary if we have multiple list with different values through this if condition

Comment: @Shiva I think you should ask a new question for this, it would be to much questions fit into one post, then i could answer it there, and also other users can answer too, more users will see your question.

Comment: @Shiva Okay, i will focus and try to help you :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919964/appeding-different-list-values-to-dictionary-in-python

Comment: @Shiva Saw it. :D

Comment: @Shiva Answered it :-)