# Appeding different list values to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I have three lists containing different pattern of values. This should append specific values only inside a single dictionary based on some if condition.I have tried the following way to do so but i got all the values from the list.

```
class_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

boxes = [[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9],[0.7,0.9,0.4,0.2],[0.9,0.7,0.6,0.3],[0.9,0.14,0.6,0.3],[0.9,0.7,0.6,0.13]]

scores = [0.98,0.87,0.97,0.96,0.94,0.92]

k=1;

data = {}

for a in scores:
    for b in boxes:
        for c in list:
            if a >= 0.98:
                data[k+1] = {"score":a,"box":b, "class": c } ;
                k=k+1;
print("Final_result",data)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use `zip`:

```
for a,b,c in zip(scores,boxes,class_list):
   if a >= 0.98:
       data[k+1] = {"score":a,"box":b, "class": c } ;
       k=k+1;
print("Final_result",data)
```

Output:

```
Final_result {2: {'score': 0.98, 'box': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 'class': 1}}
```

**Edit:**

```
for a,b,c in zip(scores,boxes,class_list):
   if a >= 0.98:
       data[k+1] = {"score":a,"box":b, "class": int(c) } ;
       k=k+1;
print("Final_result",data)
```

Comment: i am able to get the values. but inside the dictionary the list values become float instead of integer.

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6] changes to [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]

Comment: @Shiva Updated mine.

Comment: could you explain this logic => list(map(int,b))

Comment: @Shiva That's actually just making all list elements `int` type, it's actually the same as `[int(i) for i in b]`, see http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: @Shiva which one is list array?

Comment: changed the name from list to class_list in question. those values are coming in float. we need to keep that as int only

Comment: @Shiva So integer will be 0 or 1, round up or round down?

Comment: {1: {'box': [0.46, 0.56, 0.66, 0.66], 'score': 0.98, 'class': 1.0}}, here class must be only 1 not 1.0

Comment: @Shiva Happy to help again!, :-),  

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all values because you are looping over all values with all the other values i.e 6x6x6 times.
I understood your problem, what you need to use is Zip feature.

```
llist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

boxes = [[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.5,0.7,0.8,0.9],[0.7,0.9,0.4,0.2],[0.9,0.7,0.6,0.3],[0.9,0.14,0.6,0.3],[0.9,0.7,0.6,0.13]]

scores = [0.98,0.87,0.97,0.96,0.94,0.92]

k=1;

data = {}



for a,b,c in zip(scores, boxes, llist):
    if a >= 0.98:
        data[k] = {"score":a,"box":b, "class": c } ;
        k = k + 1

for k in data.keys():
    print(k , data[k])
```

ps: Avoid naming your variables with Keywords, list is a keyword. Might face problem and you even be able to find the cause.

Comment: Isn't this the same as mine?

Comment: Guess we posted at same time.

Comment: No, i answered 10 minutes faster than you.

Comment: Fine my bad, i didn't see your answer, i was busy making mine

Comment: It's okay, :-), doesn't really matter :D